# Significance of using const in render to store state values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a query regarding something i saw multiple times in the react docs.

They use a constant in render method which stores the value of something from the state and then use the const for further logic.

Eg ->

```
render(){
    // showLogin is boolean
    const showLogin = this.state.showLogin
    showLogin ? return(something) : return(something else)
}
```

So my question is why not directly use **this.state.showLogin** and why create a separate const?

Is there any benefit of using this way or is it just done for no reason as such.

Documentation for example -> https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: It is simply much more readable, especially as the state object may include nested objects which will make it even harder to read and understand what the code does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example it is purely for cleaner and more readable code.
If they would use:

```
this.state.showLogin ? return(something) : return(something else)
```

there will be no difference for the machine, but imagine a real code base with many lines of codes and many state values (showLogin, toggleBar, hideNotification etc).
the code will get messy really quickly. So out of caring for next developer (and for your future self), its better to write code as clean as possible.

And regarding CONST -> if the variable wont be reassigned in the future you sould always use const instead of let.

Comment: I have yet to understand how it is "cleaner" to write more code by declaring an extra variable that is only used once in the whole scope, splitting what essentially is a one-liner into two probably disjoined lines of code that I have to read BOTH to know what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

might be the careless typing. but your question has some issues. the ternary operator has an advantage over conventional if-else, it can return value by default.

```
const color = true ? 'orange' : 'green';
```

coming to your question,

```
render(){
 const { showLogin } = this.state;

 return (
  <div>
   {showLogin ? <Component1 /> : <Component2 />}
  </div>
 )
}
```

//

```
render() {
 const { showLogin } = this.state;

 if (showLogin) {
  return <Component1 />
 } else {
  return <Component2 />
 }
}
```

and to the answer, the reasonable answer i can think of is two,

1. you are destructuring from a REACT STATE which you are not supposed to mutate it in the render() and you are not going to. you handle this with a callback() and a setState().

also as others mentioned readability and of course it is the shorter syntax.

2. Linting. It is a good practice to declare a variable as const if you are not reassigning it. Linter will complain if you don't ( this is a valid linting error ).

following lines does the same (of course there is functional difference, the first is destructuring from the state object. the second is assigning to a variable), so no worries..

```
const { showLogin } = this.state;
const showLogin = this.state.showLogin
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
render(){
    // showLogin is boolean
    const showLogin = this.state.showLogin
    showLogin ? return(something) : return(something else)
}
```

does the same thing as

```
render(){
    // this.state.showLogin is boolean
    this.state.showLogin ? return(something) : return(something else)
}
```

The difference is not the logic of the code, the difference is readability.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the readability. You will also found `object destructuring` in some cases. 
like `const {showLogin, otherProperty} = this.state;`
It just improves the readability of your code.